# Trying to complete Simple Interval Scheduling

Tags: python, dataframe, permutation

Trying to complete Interval scheduling using Python code and thinking Dataframes would be easiest.

Say I have

```
1 = Available
0 = !Available

Person   Day1    Day2
---------------------
1        1        0
2        1        1
3        0        1
4        1        1
```

And

```
1 = Needed
0 = !Needed

Jobsite Day1     Day2
----------------------
1        1        0
2        0        1
```

I some available schedules are ((P1,J1)(P2,J2)) or ((P2,J1),(P3,J2)), etc.
My initial thought is 3 For loops

```
Collect_df = pd.dataframe()
iter = 0
For iter < Person_DF.shape[0]
 For p_row in Person_DF
  For J in Jobsite_DF
   For p_col in p_row
    For j_col in J
     If p_col == 1 AND j_col == 1
      Collect_df = Collect_df.append(pair_one = [p_col,j_col]
      p_col = 0
      j_col = 0

some code to check if at the end and loop back around Person_DF 


 If collect_df != 'Sum of all jobsite days'
        not a full Schedule, delete it
 else
        Keep this as a possible complete schedule
```

That feels Wrong and clunky. Also I would have to re-iterate every time (and loop back around, so if I started at P3 on the third iteration, I would have to do P4, P1, P2 to make every possible pairing).

Does anyone have a better solution or able to help me out? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you be more clear on the output you desire? Do you need all possible combinations that are available? (so job needed and person available?)
Does it need to be comprehensive in the sense that I can't use person_X more than 1 time on any day?

Comment: Correct on " I can't use person_X more than 1 time on any day?" Just valid schedules coming back. I think that's easy enough by sumnation of all rows at the end of each iteration. if Job's has any sum >1, schedule wont work?